# Django settings not found when trying to deploy

Tags: python, django, divio

I have my Django app settings in a folder within the app folder with an **init**.py and this works fine on my current VPS server, Pycharm development and in the Divio local development environment. However, when I try and deploy this to Divio staging I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'". Why is this?

Manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from aldryn_django import startup


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
    startup.manage(path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

No settings.py file

Folder called settings with:

_ *init* _.py

```
from .dev_divio import *  # or .dev if you want dev
from .common import *

INSTALLED_ADDONS = [
    # <INSTALLED_ADDONS>  # Warning: text inside the INSTALLED_ADDONS tags is auto-generated. Manual changes will be overwritten.
    'aldryn-addons',
    'aldryn-django',
    'aldryn-sso',
    # </INSTALLED_ADDONS>
]

import aldryn_addons.settings
aldryn_addons.settings.load(locals())

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS.extend([
    # add your project specific apps here
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'appname',
])
```

which imports:

common.py
dev_divio.py

The two files above have the config in.

Comment: can you post your setup?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Divio's support?

Comment: When you get different results in the local environment and the cloud, one very useful debugging step is to [run the local server in live configuration](http://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/local-in-live-mode.html). This helps eliminate some of the few differences between them. Do you see the same error when in live configuration?

Comment: Have posted more on setup above.

Comment: do you have a settings file inside simpris folder?

Comment: No actual settings.py file at all.

Comment: I have amended and improved my answer below with a better, simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there.

## How Django finds its settings in Divio projects

Your change to `manage.py` allowed the `collectstatic` executed by the Dockerfile:

```
RUN DJANGO_MODE=build python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

to find the settings correctly. In effect, you hard-coded the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable into the `manage.py`.

This will allow any `manage.py` command to find the settings, so (as you discovered) you'd be able to run the site locally.

However, other commands *also* need to know where the settings are, such as the `start web` command that is used in Cloud deployments, or locally if you [run the local server in live configuration](http://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/local-in-live-mode.html).

These commands rely on a correctly-set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`environment variable, and that can be set locally in `.env-local`, or for Cloud servers using the *Environment variables* view in the Control Panel.

However, environment variables set this way will only be available when containers are launched from an image that has *already been built*. They will not be available for the `collectstatic` command that's in the Dockerfile, because at this stage the image is *being built*.

It's inelegant to have to provide the same information twice, and especially to hard-code an environment variable in a Python module.

## The best solution

In fact you don't need to do *either* of these things. Instead of amending `manage.py` *and* customising the environment variable for each each environment, add:

```
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings
```

to the Dockerfile (before any Django commands are executed).

This will make the variable immediately available, and will also bake it into the image, so that each container that is created from it will contain that variable by default.

Variables set this way can still be overridden on a per-environment basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did what you suggested and it deployed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Please do mark the question as answered, as this will help others too.